# How can a hierarchical menu be made dynamically in PyroCMS?

Tags: php, pyrocms

I am using *PyroCMS Version 1.1.0*. It has the *navigation* module that is used to show up menus in front end. But I couldn't find the way out to generate *hierarchical menus* like I am working on *category* module. And in this, I have to generate a menu *Category* under which I have to show up **multi-level menus** for *categories* and *subcategories*.

Please help me with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each link can have a "parent". Just go to the Navigation page and do it.

This does not support Page Children and the interface is not as awesome as it could be, but those changes are coming in 1.2.